# Форма для группы vk.com

Tags: вконтакте

Хочу сделать форму в своей группе vk.com

В общем, почитал документацию, создал приложение для сообщества, тип "Встраиваемое приложение", там вставил юрл на форму, которая отображается в iframe. Все очень просто, кроме одного момента.

При запуске этого приложения выходит сообщение "Вы собираетесь запустить приложение ... Запустить?". Я посмотрел другие приложения, они запускаются без такого запроса.

В документации ответа не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать это предупреждение?

PS Я видел приложения в вк, где можно собрать свою форму, но мне нужна специфическая логика для формы, которую можно только написать самому, поэтому уже готовые универсальные формы не подходят, нужна своя

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно добавить свое приложение в общий каталог, что бы им могли пользоваться все. Но перед добавлением в общий каталог приложение проходит модерацию где оценивают, насколько это приложение нужно пользователям. В общем, что-то специфическое только для себя добавить нельзя без предупреждений при запуске.